# angular 5 ngSwitch not working after ng build

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I'm using Angular 5 with Angular CLI 1.6.8.  In one of my templates, I have the following piece of markup that works perfectly fine with `ng serve`, but fails with `ng build`:

```
     <div [ngSwitch]="amazonReportResultType">
        <div *ngSwitchCase="'AmazonReportEarningsByProductResponse'">
           <app-amazon-earnings-by-product-view [salesReport]="amazonReportResult"></app-amazon-earnings-by-product-view>
        </div>
        <div *ngSwitchCase="'AmazonReportEarningsByPlatformResponse'">
           <app-amazon-earnings-by-platform-view [salesReport]="amazonReportResult"></app-amazon-earnings-by-platform-view>
        </div>
     </div>
```

The rest of my app seems work fine after the build. My build command is this:

`ng build --prod --env=prod --build-optimizer --sourcemaps`

When I inspect the DOM, at the place where I'm supposed to see the output of the switch, I see an empty comment. Why is this happening and is there a workaround?

Thanks.

Comment: What happens if you add `<div *ngSwitchDefault>Oops, it was none of what I expected</div>` inside the outer div? What is printed if you add `{{ amazonReportResultType }}` before the div? Have you tried upgrding to Angular 6 and to the latest CLI?

Comment: Do you get amazonReportResultType in async?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I found the problem and it wasn't related to ngSwitch. The problem was that I was getting the value of `amazonReportResultType` by looking at `amazonReportResult.constructor.name`, and this technique doesn't work well with the uglifyJS plugin that angular cli uses. I solved this by adding a method that checks the type of the report by using `if (amazonReportResult instanceof ...)` statements and returning a string in each `if` clause. I understand that the issue can be resolved by running `ng eject` and configuring the uglify plugin, but I didn't want to go down that road.